# How to fire edit mode on a MatChipRow

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using MatChipGrid and MatChipRow to connect to an input field. Right now setting `[editable]="true"` on my mat-chip-rows allows a user to double click on a chip and edit it, and I want to be able to "fire" that editing event on my own (I prefer a single click instead of a double for that).

I've been searching for hours and couldn't find anything on the official documentation for that, except something called MatChipEditInput that has very poor documentation.
I thought maybe I should give up and just implement that editing on my own but I'm satisfied with the way angular material implemented chip editing and there's no reason for me to reinvent the wheel